# Remove everything before "http://..." in string

Tags: regex

I have a txt with line like these ones:

```
155The Last Goodnight - Stay Beautiful by CapitolMusic  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5c2iTcSlbE
156Sara Evans - A Real Fine Place To Start by saraevansVEVO http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrdCBkXB91I
157Simple Minds - See The Lights by SimpleMindsVEVO http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmKTMAak710
```

I want to remove everything before "http://..." in order to reach this result:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5c2iTcSlbE
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrdCBkXB91I
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmKTMAak710
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I can't try anything reasonable, becouse I'm new to reg exp. I've tryed to use reg exp builder as [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), [expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) and [regexpbuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/). Simply I can't understand how to start. I've tried an 1 hour before posting here (I know there are lots of know-all ready to put -1)

Comment: I get the frustration. Regex is not something that you can reference on a need to know basis, and a cheatsheet is of no use if you have never sat down and practised it, but many regex tutorials treat it as such/ assume too much. Waste of an hour!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
.*(?=http://)
```

matches everything before the last `http://` in a line.

Comment: @user128806: Yes, just use `.*?` instead of `.*`.

Answer (score 2):

**In Java**:

```
justHttp = justHttp.replaceFirst(".*(?=http://)", "");
```

For any other use just replace `http://` with `yourString`.